# Date Format For Google Classroom API ScheduledTime

Tags: date, google-api, timestamp, java-time, google-classroom

I'm trying to set the scheduled time when creating an assignment using the Google Classroom API. However, I'm confused about which date format is needed. By the error messages, it seems to accept a string which holds a timestamp and a timezone or Z at the end. Among others, I've tried using `System.currentTimeMillis() + "Z"`, as well as `googleDate.getValue() + "Z"`, `googleDate.getValue()` since Google Date format seems to be the way to go based on [this doc](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/classroom/v1/classroom-api.json)  but none of them seem to work.

Any ideas perhaps?

Thank you.

```
  String timezone = timestamp + offset + "";
                System.currentTimeMillis()
                com.google.api.client.util.DateTime googleDate = 
   new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(new java.util.Date());
//               Date javaDate = new Date(googleDate.getValue());

                CourseWork courseWork = new CourseWork()
                        .setCourseId(course.getId())
                        .setTitle("title PUBLISHED 2")
                        .setDescription("desc")
                        .setScheduledTime(googleDate.getValue() + "Z")
                        .setMaxPoints(100.0)
                        .setDueDate(date)
                        .setDueTime(timeOfDay)
                        .setWorkType("ASSIGNMENT")
                        .setState("PUBLISHED")
                        ;
```

This is what I get when I manually add a timestamp and turn it into a string.
[image]

And this using the Google date instead.

[image]

[image]

And this with the new Java 8 apis

[image]

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date` on the Java side. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant`or some other class both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It will likely also give you the format Google needs for free.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have updated the post with a screenshot of what I get with the java 8 apis. Same error I'm afraid.

Comment: Tried this now  ```Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal");
                    ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(z);
                    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withLocale(Locale.CANADA);
                    String output = zdt.format(f);```

Comment: The imports were actually the problem. I've just found out and posted the answer for this. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
                    java.util.Date date1 = java.util.Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay()
                                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                    .toInstant());

                    String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").format(date1);
```

It seems the imports were using the Google Date class instead of java.util.date.

Comment: I still recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date` and so much more that you stay far away from `SimpleDateFormat`, a notoriously troublesome and long outdated class.

Comment: (And I was right about `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` :-)

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. The following code gives the same result as the code from your answer.

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
    String s = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output in my time zone today:

> 2021-10-20T00:00:00+02:00

Compared to your own answer you have fewer conversions, and you are freed from writing your own format pattern string since the formatter we need is built in.